# No encuentro el Windows Form Designer en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, windows-forms, formularios, vba

Soy nuevo con visual Studio, estoy intentando trabajar en una solución de windows forms usando git, cloné los datos de un repositorio que trabajo conjunto a un compañero de la universidad y los archivos del repositorio aparecen "bloqueados" en visual studio, se pueden editar pero tiene un ícono de candado que no entiendo:

[image: IMG1]

El problema es que al intentar abrir el form designer de visual studio dando click derecho a la clase dedicada, no me aaparece la opción de usar el form designer y no entiendo la razón, ¿alguno tiene una idea de la razón de esto?

[image: img2]

espero la respuesta, gracias.

Comment: Boton derecho sobre Form1.vb opcion ver diseño!

Comment: En la segunda imagen del post eso es lo que hice, le di click derecho pero la opción de "ver diseño" no aparece.

Answer (score 0):

el icono del candando significa que el proyecto esta coenctado en git y que si no modificas el archivo te saldra el candado como que esta igual que en el Git. Es un control visual para que veas que esta modificado y que no lo esta.

Despues para el designer si le haces doble click deberia de abrirte la pantalla visual para el disenyo del form. Ahora si quieres ver el codigo dale en abrir con... te saldra un listado de como quieres abrirlo.

Comment: Gracias! Entiendo lo del candado ahora, pero respecto a el problema del form designer, no, no me despliega la herramienta de drag and drop para diseñar el form, incluso con click derecho no me aparece la opción para usar la herramienta siquiera.